# AMD chipset VS SLi

Tags: motherboard, sli, am3

I currently own a Crosshair 2 Formula which is broken and I need to replace. Recently, I bought a Phenom 2 CPU which I wouldn't like to throw away.

Recent Crosshairs are based (as opposed to the Rampage series) on chipsets that are certified for AMD Crossfire.

The problem is that I have 3 SLi cards I absolutely don't want to change with AMD card(s) since I use 3D Vision, and I need NVidia.

If I buy a Crosshair 3 or 4 which is not SLi certified, will SLi still work? Else, could you suggest me a good gaming motherboard with AM3 socket and that works with 3-way SLi?

Thank you in advance.

[Edit] I'm asking this question because it seems Crosshair 2 is difficult to find among the market

Comment: Unfortunately, according to [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq), this site is not about shopping recommendation. For the other part of the question, you need SLI certified motherboard. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, it's on top:"and it is not about …

    * videogames or consoles
    * websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
    * electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
    * **a shopping or buying recommendation**
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I buy a Crosshair 3 or 4 which is not SLi certified, will SLi still work?

No.